# How to increase line thickness in an existing raster image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I received an image with colored lines that I need to include in a report.
However, the image will be scaled down and the lines will be thin making it hard to see what color they are (especially in print).

This is a sample of the image. It doesn't make sense on its own, but it's just to show what my source image is.
[image]

Can I somehow increase the thickness of these lines? Somehow make them bleed to the surrounding area *in their original colour*?
The latter aspect is important so a glow (of one colour) is not going to cut it.

If other software is more suitable to do this, please do share. Photoshop was just my first idea.

Comment: If it's all one image, with the text labels as well, there's nothing you can easily do to alter only the lines. Anything will alter the text as well. If the text is on a separate layer, you could try `Filter > Other > Minimum` to increase the lines.

Comment: Wow, that works really well! Too bad my image indeed isn't layered and the text is affected as well, but maybe I can work around it using color select.

Comment: You could always extract the text to it's own layer and remove it from the lines, then run the filter.

Comment: The nature of the image is important as well. If it's possibly a vector image in a PDF or eps then you could *easily* alter the lines in Illustrator.

Comment: I ended up extracting the text and applying the minimum filter with reasonable results. The legibility of the text is not very important. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. It's a pdf but not of a vector image, it's rasterized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract the text to its own layer.

Then on the line layer run `Filter > Other... > Minimum` which will allow you to add pixels to the line while retaining the colors.

(Minimum adds pixels, Maximum subtracts them)